# should python asyncio task always return something?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, rules

It may sound like a dumb questions but I could not find a clear answer .

[I can read, in the asyncio doc here:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)

> `done()`
> Return True if the Task is done.
>
> A Task is done when the wrapped coroutine either returned a value, raised an exception, or the Task was cancelled.

does this mean that whatever coroutine I created , It must always return something and not simply end when the job is done  ??
If yes , what is the most pythonic way to do it ?
`return 0` or  `return None` ?

Comment: Every Python function/coroutine returns ``None`` implicitly when it is ended without raising an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All python functions return `None` upon completion if not explicitly provided a return value so you don't need to explicitly return anything. If you need to return early you can use just `return` without any value which is equivalent to `return None`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer